# Custom-shaped QWidgets disappearing

Tags: qt, qt4, widget, qwidget

I am unsuccessfully trying to modify Qt's WindowFlags example in order to have a custom Widget. At first it seems quite easy, but I can't figure out why it doesn't work.

The **only** addition to the example is in the `PreviewWindow` class, in its constructor:

```
QVector<QPoint> pts;

pts.push_back(QPoint(0, 10));
pts.push_back(QPoint(36, 10));
pts.push_back(QPoint(36+10, 0));
pts.push_back(QPoint(36+20, 10));
pts.push_back(QPoint(296, 10));
pts.push_back(QPoint(296, 266));
pts.push_back(QPoint(0, 266));

QPolygon p(pts);

setMask(QRegion(pts));
```

Now, when I run the example with this addition, I don't get a nice looking window. But, that's not what I wanted: those coordinates refer only to the **Qt::Tool** type of window.

The shape is OK as a Tool (just try), but now I want to *get rid of the window frame*. Unfortunately, the whole window disappears in despair.

What should I do?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know why this is happening, but here it is.

First of all, after setting flags, a widget will disappear, but I was relaxed, since the code in the controller window called `PreviewWindow::show()` right after setting flags (in `ControllerWindow::updatePreview()`).

However, we need to call show **right after setting flags** in the PreviewWindow class, as below:

```
void PreviewWindow::setWindowFlags(Qt::WindowFlags flags)
{
    QWidget::setWindowFlags(flags);

    // This is necessary to show the window again
    show();

    QString text;

    Qt::WindowFlags type = (flags & Qt::WindowType_Mask);
    if (type == Qt::Window) {
        text = "Qt::Window";
    } else if (type == Qt::Dialog) {
        text = "Qt::Dialog";
    } else if (type == Qt::Sheet) {
        text = "Qt::Sheet";
    } else if (type == Qt::Drawer) {
        text = "Qt::Drawer";
    } else if (type == Qt::Popup) {
        text = "Qt::Popup";
    } else if (type == Qt::Tool) {
        text = "Qt::Tool";
    } else if (type == Qt::ToolTip) {
        text = "Qt::ToolTip";
    } else if (type == Qt::SplashScreen) {
        text = "Qt::SplashScreen";
    }

    if (flags & Qt::MSWindowsFixedSizeDialogHint)
        text += "\n| Qt::MSWindowsFixedSizeDialogHint";
    if (flags & Qt::X11BypassWindowManagerHint)
        text += "\n| Qt::X11BypassWindowManagerHint";
    if (flags & Qt::FramelessWindowHint)
        text += "\n| Qt::FramelessWindowHint";
    if (flags & Qt::WindowTitleHint)
        text += "\n| Qt::WindowTitleHint";
    if (flags & Qt::WindowSystemMenuHint)
        text += "\n| Qt::WindowSystemMenuHint";
    if (flags & Qt::WindowMinimizeButtonHint)
        text += "\n| Qt::WindowMinimizeButtonHint";
    if (flags & Qt::WindowMaximizeButtonHint)
        text += "\n| Qt::WindowMaximizeButtonHint";
    if (flags & Qt::WindowCloseButtonHint)
        text += "\n| Qt::WindowCloseButtonHint";
    if (flags & Qt::WindowContextHelpButtonHint)
        text += "\n| Qt::WindowContextHelpButtonHint";
    if (flags & Qt::WindowShadeButtonHint)
        text += "\n| Qt::WindowShadeButtonHint";
    if (flags & Qt::WindowStaysOnTopHint)
        text += "\n| Qt::WindowStaysOnTopHint";
    if (flags & Qt::CustomizeWindowHint)
        text += "\n| Qt::CustomizeWindowHint";

    textEdit->setPlainText(text);
}
```

So, a simple line, put in a weird place. Any hint on why this is happening?